# Visual C++ GDI+ questions: GdiplusStartup always returns 2(Invalid paramters)

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, gdi+

I tried to tested out a simple GDI+ program but could not initialize it. The GdiplusStartup returns 2 which means "invalid parameters". In debug mode, I can see *GdiplusStartupInput startInput* is initialized (GdiplusVersion=1 ....etc.) so it is not the problem.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "resource.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <gdiplus.h>

using namespace Gdiplus;
#pragma comment (lib,"Gdiplus.lib")

BOOL CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND hwnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
.... some code here ....
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    GdiplusStartupInput startInput;
    ULONG_PTR* gdiToken = 0;

    Gdiplus::Status status = Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(gdiToken, &startInput, NULL);
    return DialogBox(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), NULL, DialogProc);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument is wrong. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534077.aspx) describes it like this:

> Pointer to a ULONG_PTR that receives a token.

But you are passing a null pointer. Change the code like so:

```
GdiplusStartupInput startInput; // use default constructor to initialize struct
ULONG_PTR gdiToken;
Gdiplus::Status status = Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&gdiToken, &startInput, NULL);
```

Comment: Well, there's more to it than that.  Read the code in my answer again. You need to declare `gdiToken` to be `ULONG_PTR` and not `ULONG_PTR*` as in the code in the question. This is a very very common mistake, and you should make sure you understand it and recognise it so that you don't make it again. And of course you do need to initialize `startInput` which your code does not.

Comment: If I am not wrong, according to MSDN [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms534067(v=vs.85).aspx) GdiplusStartupInput has constructor and will initialize it, By default GdiplusVersion is 1.